# Why Getting Unknown [Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener'] in spring security? Important

Tags: spring, exception, spring-security, password-encryption

I am new in spring security and getting an unknown exception which i am unable to figure-out on my own.
**What i am trying to is:-** I am just taking the user details as an input and encoding the password field and storing it in Mysql database.

Project Structure:-

[Application file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNUMz.png)

Coding part:-

```
package io.demo.miniapi.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.demo.miniapi.modal.User;
import io.demo.miniapi.repository.UserRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/miniapi")
public class MainController 
{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @PostMapping("admin/add")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {   
        String pwd = user.getPassword();
        String encryptPwd = passwordEncoder.encode(pwd);
        user.setPassword(encryptPwd);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "User added successfully...";
    }
}
```

And security configuration java file.

```
package io.spring.miniapi.securityrepository;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encodePWD() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        
    }

}
```

And when i am running the program i am getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "task-2" 2020-07-22 12:36:18.711  INFO 5676 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:212)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
2020-07-22 12:36:18.715  INFO 5676 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-07-22 12:36:18.752  INFO 5676 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-07-22 12:36:18.755  INFO 5676 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-07-22 12:36:18.775  INFO 5676 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-07-22 12:36:19.020 ERROR 5676 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field passwordEncoder in io.demo.miniapi.controller.MainController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
```

**pom.xml file:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-miniapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-miniapi</name>
    <description>Basic API using spring data JPA and spring security</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have added security dependency so there is no problem from there.

**Please help i am preparing for interview an purpose...**

Comment: Are you using spring-boot? or just spring-mvc and spring-security? could you update the post with your pom.xml?

Comment: Post is updated....@Nico..

Comment: @Nico it working when i am adding @ComponentScan("fully qualified path to configuration package ") can you explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot by default scan the full package and subpackages where the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` is located. Looking at your project structure, you have a bad package structure (the package `io.spring.miniapi` is not inside of `io.demo.miniapi`). Usually, in java applications with maven structure, you have a root package called `[domain].[companyName]` (io.demo.miniapi for your case) and then you create subpackages within it.

So knowing that, you have two options:

1. Create the root package `io.demo.miniapi` and then inside create subpackages. Also, move your `SpringBootMiniapiApplication.java` to the root package.
2. Use `@ComponentScan` in your `SpringBootMiniapiApplication.java`.